# How to run a keyboard command in a Bash script on Windows

Tags: windows-10, powershell, bash-scripting

I was told [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925960/how-to-run-a-keyboard-command-in-a-bash-script-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment111282175_62925960) may be a better place for this question.

I am trying to open up two windows of Alacritty with bash then resize them to take half the screen each.
I thought it may be possible to use windowskey + side arrows, but I'm not too sure how to run a keyboard command and how to apply it to a program.

Here is what I have so far:

```
start alacritty
```

What I'd like to do:

```
start alacritty WINDOWSKEY LEFT ARROW # left side
start alacritty WINDOWSKEY RIGHT ARROW # right side
```

I'm running powershell, and I'd like to happen by running a script like `makewindows.sh`

Comment: Try `bash.exe makewindows.sh` if you have installed WSL or WSL2.

Comment: I know how to run the script, I'm not sure how to preform a key combo with bash, like `Tab` + `Alt`

Comment: @Will are you sure you mean bash, and not "batch" or "PowerShell"?

Comment: @SimonS like I'm running a `.sh` script, which I thought was a bash file. I'm running it in powershell.